# Konva serialization and deserialization of a custom shape

Tags: konva

How do you serialize and deserialize a custom Konva Shape?

Konva allows you to create a custom shape with the sceneFunc, but when you store it to JSON and load it back, how do you know what custom shape it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define a custom shape you need to define `sceneFunc` [Demo](https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Custom.html):

```js
function mySceneFunc(context, shape) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(0, 0, shape.getAttr('width'), shape.getAttr('height'));
    context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
}

var rect = new Konva.Shape({
  fill: '#00D2FF',
  width: 100,
  height: 50,
  name: 'my-custom-rect',
  sceneFunc: mySceneFunc
});
```

It is not recommended to serialize functions into JSON. So by default `node.toJSON()` will not have `sceneFunc` property.

To restore your custom shape you just need to find such shapes in your stage after deserialization and then apply `sceneFunc` manually. You can set your own name to such shapes to easily find them.

```js
var json =
        '{"attrs":{"width":758,"height":300},"className":"Stage","children":[{"attrs":{},"className":"Layer","children":[{"attrs":{"fill":"#00D2FF","width": 100, "height": 100, "name": "my-custom-rect" },"className":"Shape"}]}]}';

// create node using json string
var stage = Konva.Node.create(json, 'container');

function mySceneFunc(context, shape) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(0, 0, shape.getAttr('width'), shape.getAttr('height'));
    context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
}

stage.find('.my-custom-rect').sceneFunc(mySceneFunc);
stage.draw()
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/sadehigina/1/edit?html,js,output